# How to make a rotated cuboid changing the orientation with respect a point and keep the items on it

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry, rotating, tikz-3dplot

I would like to make a representation of a cardboard box changing the relative position with respect to a fixed Reader, like this,

[image]

The two boxes are identical, but the top box lies on the narrow-long face, and the bottom box lies on a different side of the box, on the wide face.

However, I can not make the bottom box have that orientation with respect to the Reader.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@cuboid@get#1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cuboid/#1}}
\def\tikz@lib@cuboid@setup{%
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vxx}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{xscale}*cos(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{xangle})*1cm}
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vxy}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{xscale}*sin(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{xangle})*1cm}
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vyx}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{yscale}*cos(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{yangle})*1cm}
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vyy}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{yscale}*sin(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{yangle})*1cm}
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vzx}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{zscale}*cos(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{zangle})*1cm}
   \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vzy}%
      {\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{zscale}*sin(\tikz@lib@cuboid@get{zangle})*1cm}
}
\def\tikz@lib@cuboid@draw#1--#2--#3\pgf@stop{%
    \begin{scope}[join=bevel,x={(\vxx,\vxy)},y={(\vyx,\vyy)},z={(\vzx,\vzy)}]
       % first fill the faces with global and individual style
       % then draw the grids
       \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=#1]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/edges,cuboid/right face] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#2,0) -- ++(0,-#3) -- ++(-#2,0) -- cycle;
          \draw[cuboid/all grids,cuboid/right grid] (0,0) grid (#2,-#3);
       \end{scope}
       \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/edges,cuboid/front face] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#1,0) --  ++(0,#2) -- ++(-#1,0) -- cycle;
          \draw[cuboid/all grids,cuboid/front grid] (0,0) grid (#1,#2);
       \end{scope}
       \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=#2]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/edges,cuboid/top face] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#1,0) --  ++(0,-#3) -- ++(-#1,0) -- cycle;
          \draw[cuboid/all grids,cuboid/top grid] (0,0) grid (#1,-#3);
       \end{scope}
       % now, draw the hidden edges
       \draw[cuboid/hidden edges] (0,#2,-#3) -- (0,0,-#3) -- (0,0,0) 
                (0,0,-#3) -- ++(#1,0,0);
       % finally, draw the visible edges 
       \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=#1]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/right face,cuboid/edges,fill opacity=0] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#2,0) -- ++(0,-#3) -- ++(-#2,0) -- cycle;
       \end{scope}
       \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/front face,cuboid/edges,fill opacity=0] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#1,0) --  ++(0,#2) -- ++(-#1,0) -- cycle;
       \end{scope}
       \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=#2]
          \draw[cuboid/all faces,cuboid/top face,cuboid/edges,fill opacity=0] 
                (0,0) -- ++(#1,0) --  ++(0,-#3) -- ++(-#1,0) -- cycle;
       \end{scope}
       % define the anchors: 8 vertices
       \path (0,#2,0) coordinate (-left top front)
                      coordinate (-left front top)
                      coordinate (-top left front)
                      coordinate (-top front left)
                      coordinate (-front top left)
                      coordinate (-front left top);
       \path (0,#2,-#3) coordinate (-left top rear)
                        coordinate (-left rear top)
                        coordinate (-top left rear)
                        coordinate (-top rear left)
                        coordinate (-rear top left)
                        coordinate (-rear left top);
       \path (0,0,-#3) coordinate (-left bottom rear)
                       coordinate (-left rear bottom)
                       coordinate (-bottom left rear)
                       coordinate (-bottom rear left)
                       coordinate (-rear bottom left)
                       coordinate (-rear left bottom);
       \path (0,0,0) coordinate (-left bottom front)
                     coordinate (-left front bottom)
                     coordinate (-bottom left front)
                     coordinate (-bottom front left)
                     coordinate (-front bottom left)
                     coordinate (-front left bottom);
       \path (#1,#2,0) coordinate (-right top front)
                       coordinate (-right front top)
                       coordinate (-top right front)
                       coordinate (-top front right)
                       coordinate (-front top right)
                       coordinate (-front right top);
       \path (#1,#2,-#3) coordinate (-right top rear)
                         coordinate (-right rear top)
                         coordinate (-top right rear)
                         coordinate (-top rear right)
                         coordinate (-rear top right)
                         coordinate (-rear right top);
       \path (#1,0,-#3) coordinate (-right bottom rear)
                        coordinate (-right rear bottom)
                        coordinate (-bottom right rear)
                        coordinate (-bottom rear right)
                        coordinate (-rear bottom right)
                        coordinate (-rear right bottom);
       \path (#1,0,0) coordinate (-right bottom front)
                      coordinate (-right front bottom)
                      coordinate (-bottom right front)
                      coordinate (-bottom front right)
                      coordinate (-front bottom right)
                      coordinate (-front right bottom);
       % centers of the 6 faces
       \coordinate (-left center) at (0,.5*#2,-.5*#3);
       \coordinate (-right center) at (#1,.5*#2,-.5*#3);
       \coordinate (-top center) at (.5*#1,#2,-.5*#3);
       \coordinate (-bottom center) at (.5*#1,0,-.5*#3);
       \coordinate (-front center) at (.5*#1,.5*#2,0);
       \coordinate (-rear center) at (.5*#1,.5*#2,-#3);
       % center of the cuboid
       \coordinate (-center) at (.5*#1,.5*#2,-.5*#3);
       % centers of the 12 edges
       \path (0,#2,-.5*#3) coordinate (-left top center) 
                           coordinate (-top left center);
       \path (.5*#1,#2,-#3) coordinate (-top rear center)
                            coordinate (-rear top center);
       \path (#1,#2,-.5*#3) coordinate (-right top center)
                            coordinate (-top right center);
       \path (.5*#1,#2,0) coordinate (-top front center)
                          coordinate (-front top center);
       \path (0,0,-.5*#3) coordinate (-left bottom center) 
                           coordinate (-bottom left center);
       \path (.5*#1,0,-#3) coordinate (-bottom rear center)
                            coordinate (-rear bottom center);
       \path (#1,0,-.5*#3) coordinate (-right bottom center)
                            coordinate (-bottom right center);
       \path (.5*#1,0,0) coordinate (-bottom front center)
                          coordinate (-front bottom center);
       \path (0,.5*#2,0) coordinate (-left front center) 
                           coordinate (-front left center);
       \path (0,.5*#2,-#3) coordinate (-left rear center)
                            coordinate (-rear left center);
       \path (#1,.5*#2,0) coordinate (-right front center)
                            coordinate (-front right center);
       \path (#1,.5*#2,-#3) coordinate (-right rear center)
                          coordinate (-rear right center);
    \end{scope}
}
\tikzset{
  pics/cuboid/.style = {
    setup code = \tikz@lib@cuboid@setup,
    background code = \tikz@lib@cuboid@draw#1\pgf@stop
  },
  pics/cuboid/.default={1--1--1},
  cuboid/.is family,
  cuboid,
  all faces/.style={fill=white},
  all grids/.style={draw=none},
  front face/.style={},
  front grid/.style={},
  right face/.style={},
  right grid/.style={},
  top face/.style={},
  top grid/.style={},
  edges/.style={},
  hidden edges/.style={draw=none},
  xangle/.initial=0,
  yangle/.initial=90,
  zangle/.initial=210,
  xscale/.initial=1,
  yscale/.initial=1,
  zscale/.initial=0.5}
\newcommand{\tikzcuboidreset}{
  \tikzset{cuboid,
    all faces/.style={fill=white},
    all grids/.style={draw=none},
    front face/.style={},
    front grid/.style={},
    right face/.style={},
    right grid/.style={},
    top face/.style={},
    top grid/.style={},
    edges/.style={},
    hidden edges/.style={draw=none},
    xangle=-20,
    yangle=90,
    zangle=180,
    xscale=1,
    yscale=1,
    zscale=0.5}}
\newcommand{\tikzcuboidset}{\@ifstar\tikzcuboidset@star\tikzcuboidset@nostar} 
\newcommand{\tikzcuboidset@nostar}[1]{\tikzcuboidreset\tikzset{cuboid,#1}}
\newcommand{\tikzcuboidset@star}[1]{\tikzset{cuboid,#1}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  cuboid face/.style={
    shift=(#1-left bottom front),
    x=(#1-right bottom front),
    y=(#1-left top front),
    canvas is xy plane at z=0,
  }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[black, draw, very thick, shift={(0,1)}, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=2cm] (R) {\Large Reader};
    
    \tikzcuboidset{hidden edges/.style={dashed}}
    \pic[very thick,black] (cuboid) at (4,0,0) {cuboid=3--3--3};
    
    \foreach[count=\i] \p/\t in {(.3, .1)/A, (.7, .6)/B, (.25, .7)/C}
    \fill[red, cuboid face=cuboid] \p rectangle coordinate (\t) +(.05,.1) coordinate (@)
      (\t) node[above, scale=.4, transform shape] at (\t|-@) {\t}
      (R.east) edge[blue, dashed, very thick, -latex] node[above]{$d_\i$} (\t);
    
          
          
           \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-5)}]
             \node[black, draw, very thick, shift={(0,1)}, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=2cm] (R) {\Large Reader};
             \tikzcuboidset{hidden edges/.style={dashed}}
             \pic[very thick,black] (cuboid) at (4,0,0) {cuboid=3--1.3--6};
             
             \node[draw, red,fill=red,thick, minimum width=0.1cm, scale=0.75,  rotate =90, minimum height=0.5cm,label={[font=\large,text=red]20:A}] (A) at ([shift={(-1, -0)}] cuboid-top center)  {};
           \end{scope}
    
   \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make the bottom box I have changed the cuboid 3 dimensions but I have found three issues:

- First, I am not sure that the dimensions of the bottom box are the
  same as the top box. I would like the two to have the same dimensions.
- Second, the orientation with respect to the Reader is not the desired
  orientation. I have tried to make a different `cuboid \tikzset`
  replicating the existing `cuboid` code, but I can not get the solution.
- Finally, I should have also a second `\tikzset{cuboid face/.style=` for the top face of the bottom box, which I do not know how to implement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an approach slightly different (but adaptable) that uses `isometric view` from `perspective library`. You can change this view for any other if you don't like it.

I draw the rectangles using the `3d` library options `canvas is ... plane at...` and the rectangle with the nodes A,B,C as a `pic` to avoid repeating code.

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\tikzset
{
   abc/.style={fill=red,text=white,transform shape},
   pics/my rectangle/.style={
      code={
        \draw (-2,-1.5) rectangle (2,1.5);
        \node[abc=A] (-A) at (-1.3,0.5)  {\small A};
        \node[abc=B] (-B) at (0.7,0)     {\small B};
        \node[abc=C] (-C) at (-1.3,-0.6) {\small C};
      }
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,isometric view,rotate around z=180]
  \node[draw,canvas is xz plane at y=0,xscale=-1,transform shape] (reader) at (4,0) {READER};
  \pic [canvas is yz plane at x=0] (1) {my rectangle};
  \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=1.5] (0,-2) rectangle (-1,2);
  \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=2] (0,-1.5) rectangle (-1,1.5);
  \foreach[count=\ii]\i in {A,B,C}
    \draw[cyan,dashed,-latex] (reader.east) -- (1-\i) node[pos=0.7,above] {\small$d_\ii$};
  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-3cm)}]
    \pic [canvas is xy plane at z=-0.5,rotate=-90] (2) {my rectangle};
    \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=1.5] (-2,-1.5) rectangle (2,-0.5);
    \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=2] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,-0.5);
    \node[draw,fill=white,canvas is xz plane at y=0,xscale=-1,transform shape] (reader) at (4,0) {READER};
    \foreach[count=\ii]\i in {A,B,C}
      \draw[cyan,dashed,-latex] (reader.east) -- (2-\i) node[pos=0.7,above] {\small$d_\ii$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gj Juan. what makes "Reader" invariant to the transform? is it `transform shape`?

Comment: @anis, `transform shape` is needed so 'READER' is viewed with the perspective of the xz plane (in both cases). There is no other transform, only a shift that, of course, doesn't change the view

Comment: @JuanCastaño I would like to thank you for your help. I have been trying to see how to change some parts of the figure but I can not make it. How can I rotate and translate the bottom box but keep the Reader in the same place?. I have tried `rotate around z =-10` but it also rotates the Reader node. Besides, I would like to leave a little more distance to the Reader node. I have tried `\begin{scope}[shift={(-1,-3cm)},...` but also moves the Reader node.

Comment: @pablo, for the changes in the bottom box do them locally in the options of the rectangles: `\pic[rotate...` or `draw[rotate...`. Or make another `scope` for the rectangles and left out the 'reader' node. For the distance to the 'reader' node change the 4 in `\node[...] (reader) at (4,0) {READER};`

Comment: @JuanCastaño Thank you, I will try it. As a last comment, and although probably it is not isometric, is it possible to reduce the angles between xy and   zy to make the view closer to the base of the box?

Comment: @pablo, I don't know exactly what you have in mind, but try changing the perspective. Instead of `isometric view` use something like `3d view={110}{30}` (or try other angles)

Comment: @JuanCastaño I have posted a new question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/688984/178274) using your solution but changing the cuboid face where items A, B, and C are placed