# How change the cuboid side where items A, B, C are located

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry, 3d, rotating, tikz-3d

I would like to change this isometric figure

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\tikzset
{
   abc/.style={fill=red,text=white,transform shape},
   pics/my rectangle/.style={
      code={
        \draw (-2,-1.5) rectangle (2,1.5);
        \node[abc=A] (-A) at (-1.3,0.5)  {\small A};
        \node[abc=B] (-B) at (1.3,0)     {\small B};
        \node[abc=C] (-C) at (-1.3,-0.6) {\small C};
      }
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,isometric view,rotate around z=180]
    
  \node[draw,canvas is xz plane at y=0,xscale=-1,transform shape] (reader) at (4,0) {{READER}};
  \begin{scope}[shift={(-1.,0)}, rotate around z=-7] 
    \pic [canvas is yz plane at x=0] (1) {my rectangle};
    \draw[canvas is xy plane at z=1.5] (0,-2) rectangle (-1,2);
    \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=2] (0,-1.5) rectangle (-1,1.5);
  \end{scope}
  
 \draw[cyan,dashed,-latex] (reader.east) -- (1-A) node[pos=0.5,above, sloped, xslant=-0] {\small $d_1$};
 \draw[cyan,dashed,-latex] (reader.east) -- (1-B) node[pos=0.5,above, sloped] {\small $d_3$};
 \draw[cyan,dashed,-latex] (reader.east) -- (1-C) node[pos=0.7,above, sloped, yshift=-0.7mm, xslant=-0] {\small $d_2$};

  \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-6cm)}, rotate around z=0]
      \begin{scope}[shift={(-10,0)}, rotate around z=20] % ANGLE SIRVE para CAMBIAR pos de la caja
        \pic [canvas is xy plane at z=-0.5,rotate=-90] (2) {my rectangle};
        \draw[canvas is yz plane at x=1.5] (-2,-1.5) rectangle (2,-0.5);
        \draw[canvas is xz plane at y=2] (-1.5,-1.5) rectangle (1.5,-0.5);
      \end{scope}
    
    \node[draw,fill=white,canvas is xz plane at y=0,xscale=-1,transform shape] (reader) at (4,0) {{READER}};

    \draw[cyan,dashed,-latex] (reader.east) -- (2-A) node[pos=0.45,below, sloped] {\small$d_3$};
    \draw[cyan,dashed,-latex] (reader.east) -- (2-B) node[pos=0.3,above, sloped] {\small$d_1$};
    \draw[cyan,dashed,-latex] (reader.east) -- (2-C) node[pos=0.5,above, sloped] {\small$d_2$};
  \end{scope}
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This code is the solution of a previous post [How to make a rotated cuboid changing the orientation with respect to a point and keep the items on it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688479/178274).
The top cuboid represents a cardboard box with items A, B, and C, on one of the faces, and the bottom box is the same but in another position with respect to the fixed `Reader`.

I would like to represent a similar scenario, with the same box in two different positions, but, changing the location of the items A, B, and C to the long narrow face of the box, like this

[image]

I was trying to change the `my rectangle` style and the canvas planes, but I could not place the items on the narrow side of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his original answer, Juan Castaño defined a `pic` named `my rectangle`. Inside it, he defined a rectangle and 3 nodes A,B and C. I don't exactly know  the reasoning behind this. but, you can define 2 new `pic`s and change their inside code to match your drawing.

```
\tikzset
{
   abc/.style={fill=red,text=white,transform shape},
   pics/my rectangle 1/.style={
      code={
        \draw (-2,-1.5) rectangle (2,1.5);
        \node[abc=A] (-A) at (-1.3,0.5)  {\small A};
        \node[abc=B] (-B) at (1.3,0)     {\small B};
        \node[abc=C] (-C) at (-1.3,-0.6) {\small C};
       }
    }, 
    pics/my rectangle 2/.style={
        code={
            \draw (0,-2) rectangle (-1,2);
            \node[abc=A,fill=green] (-A) at (-0.3,1.5)  {\small A};
            \node[abc=B,fill=green] (-B) at (-0.5,0)     {\small B};
            \node[abc=C,fill=green] (-C) at (-0.25,-0.6) {\small C};
        }
    },  
    pics/my rectangle 3/.style={
        code={
        \draw (0,-1.5) rectangle (-1,1.5);
        \node[abc=A,fill=blue] (-A) at (-0.75,1)  {\small A};
        \node[abc=B,fill=blue] (-B) at (-0.25,0)  {\small B};
        \node[abc=C,fill=blue] (-C) at (-0.5,-0.6) {\small C};
        }
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round,isometric view,rotate around z=180]
    
  \node[draw,canvas is xz plane at y=0,xscale=-1,transform shape] (reader) at (4,0) {{READER}};
  \begin{scope}[shift={(-1.,0)}, rotate around z=-7] % ANGLE SIRVE para CAMBIAR pos de la caja]
    \pic [canvas is yz plane at x=0] (1) {my rectangle 1};
    \pic [canvas is xy plane at z=1.5] {my rectangle 2};
    \pic [canvas is xz plane at y=2]{my rectangle 3};
  \end{scope}
```

See how the rectangles paths are defined by different two points. Not the best way for me but this has the advantage of changing the least amount of code lines. There is always another way to do it with Tikz.

[image]

You will note that A, B and C are flipped in a rectangle are flipped. That is a question for another post.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Do you know how I could place A, B, and C in the middle of the box side, keeping distances among them and with the edges of the side?

Comment: by manually specifying the coordinate. or you can use the `calc` tikzlibrary.